# How to Change the default BLUE border of Tab Bar in Sherlock Action Bar?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, tabview

I have searched a lot in SO..but not got any working solution.I want to change the default blue color of the tab bar which is coming in the bottom of the tab.I am able to change the color of the tab but not able to change the bottom blue color.I know that it is using default 9 patches image.But how to change that using custom style theme ?

this is my part of the xml..where i am doing the change for my tab view..

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
      <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Theme.app.tabbar.style</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Widget.app.ActionBar.TabBar</item>


</style>

<style name="Theme.app.tabbar.style" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
<item name="android:background">#80aa01</item>
<item name="background">#80aa01</item>
```

```
<style name="Widget.app.ActionBar.TabBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar">
<item name="android:background">#80aa01</item>
<item name="background">#80aa01</item>
```

The code is working perfectly.But i want to change the default blue bottom border.Please provide a solution !!

Answer (score 0):

There are several styles in the theme that affect tabs in the action bar. To style the tabs you have to set the following styles in the theme: `(android:)actionBarTabBarStyle`, `(android:)actionBarTabStyle` and `(android:)actionBarTabTextStyle` (parentheses to denote all the versions - native action bar, `ActionBarSherlock` and `ActionBarCompat`).

`(android:)actionBarTabBarStyle` affects the whole tab bar. The tab bar can be the "stacked action bar" (the whole bar below the main action bar) or part of the main action bar (in landscape orientation). With the style, you can change the background behind all tabs (one background for all of them together).

`(android:)actionBarTabStyle` affects a single tab. If you want to change the blue line, you have to set the background in the style. The default background is a [color state list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) that defines background for all the states (blue line for the selected state).

`(android:)actionBarTabTextStyle` affects the title in a single tab. You can change the title's size, color and other attributes.

Your theme should contain something like this:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabBarStyle</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

The styles should be something like this:

```xml
<style name="MyActionBarTabBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <!-- to change the blue line, change the background here -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_background</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabText">
    <!-- change text attributes here -->
</style>
```